# Installing GameClosure on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, macos, gameclosure

Does anyone know how to install GameClosure on Windows? According to the docs, on the [installation guide](http://docs.gameclosure.com/guide/install.html), only osx is supported, although they *have some success running on Linux and Windows*. Unfortunately they don't expand on how to do this and a Google turns up only one promising looking page which returns a 404 (there is a cached version but it only seems to be a half article).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now a full [**guide to installing Game Closure SDK on Windows here**](http://docs.gameclosure.com/guide/windows-guide.html) (I have also posted the contents in [pastebin here](http://pastebin.com/fWd9eMTx) in case the previous link disappears)

It's quite a process to get everything installed and configured, and looks like you can only develop for Android using the windows version of the SDK, but I may be mistaken

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully installed the GC DevKit on Windows, there are a few additional steps like creating symbolic links BEFORE trying to [install the GC DevKit](http://docs.gameclosure.com/guide/install.html).

Follow these steps carefully and you shouldn't have a problem getting it up and running. Read through them and try to understand what is required first.

1. Download the list of required items (Windows builds for Git, Node and Java) from the [install guide](http://docs.gameclosure.com/guide/install.html).
2. Open up Git Bash (find it on the start menu under Git)
3. Continue with the install guide by cloning the repo (`git clone https://github.com/gameclosure/devkit`).
4. The files would have been installed to **%USERPROFILE%** if you did not change the directory while in Git Bash.
5. Move all the files in *devkit\SDK* somewhere else but make sure they are gone from that directory.
6. Open a normal command-prompt (cmd.exe).
7. Create symbolic links for everything that WAS under the *devkit\SDK* directory using `mklink` (available in Vista and above) from the command-prompt (not the Git Bash console). The files you moved in step 5 will contain the path as text that the link should be pointed to EG: > `mklink /D "%USERPROFILE%\devkit\sdk\squill" "..\lib\squill\"`
8. JSIO is special and actually needs to exist in a sub-directory at the time of writing. Create the directory *devkit\SDK\jsio* and then create a symbolic link INSIDE that going back one more relative path. EG: > `mklink /D "%USERPROFILE%\devkit\sdk\jsio\jsio" "..\..\lib\js.io\packages\"`
9. Go back you your Git Bash console and now continue with the installation for [GC DevKit](http://docs.gameclosure.com/guide/install.html) by switching to the *devkit* directory running the `./install.sh` script as described.
10. Run basil by executing `node src/basil [command]`

If all the correct pre-requisites were in place everything should go smoothly. If basil throws errors it's more than likely the symbolic links, just check that everything is pointing to the right place and run `./install.sh` to try again.

Good luck!!

Comment: Man what a major pain. I hope they get their Windows experience sorted out.

Comment: I'm getting "Failure activating plugin JS..." errors for c:\\gameclosure\\devkit\\addons\\billing\\js and c:\\gameclosure\\devkit\\addons\\geoloc\\js. Any ideas? Could this be another "missing link"? I tried a few and they didn't resolve it.

Comment: more detail in step 7 with http://support.gameclosure.com/entries/23179367-Installing-DevKit-on-Windows . From "Open a command prompt as administrator and "cd" into the devkit directory. Then execute these commands:" ...

Comment: This is little bit confusing. Can you please create a video explaining how to install game closure.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get it installed on windows, but it's easy enough to install on linux, so I ended up using virtualbox and a linux vm. Cygwin could be another option but I didn't try it so unfortunately can't say for definite whether or not it would work